# array required, but java.lang.String found card game

Tags: arrays

I'm making a deck and card class for a game, and have encountered an error in creating and using a string array. 
my code looks like this: The error is 4 lines from the bottom where it says String undealt = ... undealt[0] and it says "array required, but java.lang.String found" and now I am confused

```
import java.util.*;
public class Deck
{
private static int currentCard = 0;
public ArrayList<Card> deck;
private String rank;
private String suit;
private String[] undealt = new String[52];

Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= suits.length; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < ranks.length; x++)
        {
            Card card = new Card(ranks[x], suits[i], values[x]);
            deck.add(card);
        }
    }
    shuffle();
}

public String toString()
{
    String undealt = "Undealt cards:\n" + undealt[0] + undealt[1] ...;
    for(int i = currentCard; i < deck.size(); i++)
    {
        int g = i - currentCard;
        undealt[g] = deck.get(i).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem relates to having a local String variable named undealt, and an instance field which is a String array also named undealt.  I don't think you really want to use the same names for these two types ... it does not seem like you want to be hiding the instance field (which is a questionable practice anyway).

Comment: @scottb now it says that the entire line is wrong. I fixed the name of String undealt to String 1 and now it gives the error: "not a statement" to that line

Comment: Did you change "undealt" to "1"? Because a variable name can not start with digit. Try "undealt1".

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you are having derives from these lines in your code:

```
private String[] undealt = new String[52];
    :
    :
    public String toString() {
        String undealt = "Undealt cards:\n" + undealt[0] + undealt[1] ...;
            :
            :
    }
```

As you can see, you have defined the variable `undealt` in *two different scopes.*  The first declaration is at the instance level, where you have declared  `undealt` to be an instance field of type `String[].`  The scope of an instance variable is the entire class in which it is defined, i.e. an instance variable can be accessed by all methods in that class.

The second declaration is at the *local block level,* where you have declared `undealt` to be a local variable of type `String.`  The scope of a local variable is limited to the block in which it is declared (blocks are delimited by curly braces).

As you can see, `undealt` is in scope twice in the method `toString(),` once as an instance field, the second time as a local variable.  The compiler has rules which it uses to resolve variable names when they conflict in this way, and will use the local variable definition.  This is called "hiding" the instance field, i.e. the local variable *hides* the instance field.

When the compiler tries to compile...

```
        String undealt = "Undealt cards:\n" + undealt[0] + undealt[1] ...;
```

it determines that `String[] undealt` is hidden, and it will resolve `undealt` as type `String.`

Therefore, when you attempt to use the array element access operator (the brackets after the variable name), the compiler gives you an error.  It has determined that `undealt` is a local `String` and therefore it does not have any array elements to access.

A good practice is to avoid ever using two variables with the same name in order to avoid potential sources of confusion such as this.  The compiler has a set of rules to use to resolve variable accesses in the case of a conflict, but these needn't be obvious to programmers and can cause confusion.